# Reading all csv files at particular folder, Merge them, and find the maximum value w.r.t. row interval

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, concatenation

I have 120 files csv files of . It includes IndexNo, date, EArray, temperature, etc.

Here Index Column is vary from 1 to 8760. 
I wants to read all csv files from folder and merge them in single file.
Once I merged these files I will have all IndexNo 120 times(i.e IndexNo 1 will have 120 rows).

after this I have to find the maximum value for EArray for each IndexNo (i.e. IndexNo 1 to 8760) and Print that Maximum EArray value row.

```
import pandas , OS, 
glob path = r'C:\Data_Input' # use your path 
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv") 
# print(all_files) 
li = [] 
for filename in all_files: 
     df = pd.read_csv(filename, skiprows=10, names=None, engine='python',header=0, encoding='unicode_escape') 
     df = df.assign(File_name=os.path.basename(filename).split('.')[0]) 
     li.append(df) 
     frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True, sort=False)


frame = frame.dropna() 
df = frame.assign(max_EArray=frame.groupby('IndexNo')['EArray'].transform('max')) df_filtered = df[df['EArray'] == df['max_EArray']] 
output = df_filtered.loc[df_filtered.ne(0).all(axis=1)]('max_EArray', axis=1) print(output.shape) 
output.to_csv('temp.csv')
```

Comment: In order for the community to help you, you need to show that you have attempted to build some code. As such, please post the code for your proposed solution and let us know where exactly you are having issues. Then the community might be able to help.

Comment: import pandas , OS, glob
path = r'C:\Data_Input' # use your path
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
# print(all_files)
li = []
for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename,  skiprows=10,  names=None, engine='python',header=0, encoding='unicode_escape')
    df = df.assign(File_name=os.path.basename(filename).split('.')[0])
    li.append(df)
frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True, sort=False)

Comment: frame = frame.dropna()
df = frame.assign(max_EArray=frame.groupby('IndexNo')['EArray'].transform('max'))
df_filtered = df[df['EArray'] == df['max_EArray']]
output = df_filtered.loc[df_filtered.ne(0).all(axis=1)]('max_EArray', axis=1)

print(output.shape)
output.to_csv('temp.csv')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your task can be quite easy done using *dask* (instead of pure *Pandas*).

One of advantages is that "out of the box" you have the possibility to get
the name of the source file from which there has been read particular row.

My solution is as follows:

1. Install *dask* (if you have not installed yet).
2. Import *dask.dataframe*:

   ```
   import dask.dataframe as dd
   ```
3. Define a function to reformat the DataFrame (called individually on
   each "partial" DataFrame read from particular *.csv* file):

   ```
   def reformat(df):
       df.path = df.path.str.extract(r'/(\w+)\.\w+')
       return df[['IndexNo', 'EArray', 'path']]
   ```

   Here you can use "normal" *Pandas* code. It changes also *path*,
   stripping the directory path, leaving only the file name (without extension).
4. Define a function to get the "max" row from each group (after grouping
   by *IndexNo*):

   ```
   def getMax(grp):
       wrk = grp.reset_index(drop=True)
       ind = wrk.EArray.idxmax()
       return wrk.loc[ind, ['EArray', 'path']]
   ```
5. Run the actual processing:

   ```
   ddf = dd.read_csv('EArray/*.csv', include_path_column=True)
   ddf = ddf.map_partitions(reformat)
   ddf = ddf.groupby('IndexNo').apply(getMax, meta={'EArray': 'i4', 'path': 'O'})
   df = ddf.compute().sort_index().reset_index()
   ```

Description:

- `'EArray/*.csv'` - specification of the bunch of source files.
  I put all source files in a dedicated subfolder (*EArray*).
- `include_path_column=True` - adds *path* column to the DataFrame, containing
  full path of the file each row has been read from.
- `map_partitions(...)` - call *reformat* function individually on each
  "partial" DataFrame.
- `groupby(...)` and `apply(...)` - generally, like in *Pandas*.
- `meta` - additional argument required in *dask* (specification of names
  and types of columns in the output DataFrame).
- `compute()` - run the processing tree, prepared by the previous instructions.
  Now the result is "normal" *Pandas* DataFrame.
- `sort_index()` and `reset_index()` - *Pandas* operations on the result of *compute()*.

For the test I prepared 3 *.csv* files, with *10* rows each:

T1.csv:

```
   IndexNo        date  EArray
0     1001  2019-01-01      20
1     1002  2019-01-02      20
2     1003  2019-01-03      20
3     1004  2019-01-04      20
4     1005  2019-01-05      20
5     1006  2019-01-06      20
6     1007  2019-01-07      20
7     1008  2019-01-08      20
8     1009  2019-01-09      20
9     1010  2019-01-10      20
```

T2.csv:

```
   IndexNo        date  EArray
0     1001  2019-01-11      22
1     1002  2019-01-12      23
2     1003  2019-01-13      24
3     1004  2019-01-14      25
4     1005  2019-01-15      26
5     1006  2019-01-16      27
6     1007  2019-01-17      28
7     1008  2019-01-18      29
8     1009  2019-01-19      30
9     1010  2019-01-20      31
```

T3.csv:

```
   IndexNo        date  EArray
0     1001  2019-01-21      35
1     1002  2019-01-22      34
2     1003  2019-01-23      33
3     1004  2019-01-24      32
4     1005  2019-01-25      31
5     1006  2019-01-26      30
6     1007  2019-01-27      29
7     1008  2019-01-28      28
8     1009  2019-01-29      28
9     1010  2019-01-30      26
```

The result of my program is:

```
   IndexNo  EArray path
0     1001      35   T3
1     1002      34   T3
2     1003      33   T3
3     1004      32   T3
4     1005      31   T3
5     1006      30   T3
6     1007      29   T3
7     1008      29   T2
8     1009      30   T2
9     1010      31   T2
```

E.g. for *IndexNo == 1001* the values of *EArray* are:
*20*, *22* and *35* foreach input file.

The result for *IndexNo == 1001* contains:

- *EArray == 35* - the max value from the 3 above,
- *T3* - the source file containing the "max" row.

I'm aware that you will have to learn *dask*, but in my opinion
it is worth to put some effort to do it.

Note that my code is quite clear and concise.
Just 7 lines in functions and 4 lined of the main program.

Comment: Thank you very much this program is working fine. @Valdi_Bo https://stackoverflow.com/users/7388477/valdi-bo